# Does immutable.js provide an api for lazy evaluation of the value of object?

Tags: javascript, immutable.js

Does immutable.js provide an api for  lazy evaluation of the value of object?

For example, I want make a value of some key in an object-like data structure to be evaluated lazily:

```
var lazyObjLike = {
  a: a.value.to.be.calculated,
  b: b.value.to.be.calculated,
  c: c.value.to.be.calculated
}
```

and I want `a.value.to.be.calculated` to be calculated only when `lazyObjLike.a` must be evaluated(used), leaving `b.value.to.be.calculated` and `c.value.to.be.calculated` untouched.

Comment: Just make the `a` property a getter?

Comment: Great idea! Thank you.